# porque no hace la peticion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

Hice este código en back porque en front marcaba el error de cors, pero ahora no me imprime la respuesta del servidor, y me marca un error en el código.

Adjunto código:

```
var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Autorization","Basic == ")
      headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
       var institution = {method:"GET",headers:headers,redirect:'follow'}

        componentDidMount() {
    fetch(``, institution,{mode: "no-cors"}, )
    
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items,
            
          });
          console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
          
        }
      )

      {error
        ? <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
        : !isLoaded 
              ? <div>Loading...</div>
              : <ul>
                   {items.map(item => {
                       return <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.name} {item.price}
                       </li>
                   })}
                     </ul>}
             
                  }
```

No se porque manda error en la primer llave, y aparte no imprime la respuesta del servidor, estoy ocupando una url para hacer la petición, que tendría que poner para que mande la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: si no tiene url :v

Comment: no tiene URL... y "me marca un error en el código"... que error marca en el código?

Comment: manda que la primer llave que esta alado de componentDidMount manda error en esa llave